# Как получить data-value из td в BS4 python

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Нужно по задумке получить вот так результат, список с такими значениями героев на странице:

name: "Hero name"

dis: "Hero disadvantage"

name записан в <td class="cell-icon" data-value="Outworld Destroyer"

disadvantage записан в data-value <td data-value="2.9031"

Вот html целиком:

```
<td class="cell-icon" data-value="Outworld Destroyer"><div class="image-container image-container-hero image-container-icon"><a href="/heroes/outworld-destroyer"><img class="image-hero image-icon" data-tooltip-url="/heroes/outworld-destroyer/tooltip" rel="tooltip-remote" src="/assets/heroes/outworld-destroyer-60496afd5b92709cbc2350ddd2257b1d6f0e1ce6dd5b2c6a4614e9ace6d2959e.jpg" title="Outworld Destroyer"/></a></div></td>, <td class="cell-xlarge"><a class="link-type-hero" href="/heroes/outworld-destroyer">Outworld Destroyer</a></td>, <td data-value="2.9031">2.90%<div class="bar bar-default"><div class="segment segment-disadvantage" style="width: 100.00000000000001%;"></div></div></td>, <td data-value="46.0201">46.02%<div class="bar bar-default"><div class="segment segment-win" style="width: 76.92954492645572%;"></div></div></td>, <td data-value="53896">53,896<div class="bar bar-default"><div class="segment segment-match" style="width: 46.159643713600545%;"></div></div></td>
```

URL = 'https://ru.dotabuff.com/heroes/abaddon/counters'
Получается вывести только 1 имя и все.

Вывод такой получил:

```
[{'name': 'Outworld Destroyer'}]
```

Вот мой "код":

```
def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    items = soup.find_all('table', class_='sortable')

    heroes = []

    for item in items:
        td = item.td['data-value']
        heroes.append({
            'name': item.td['data-value']
        })
        print(heroes)

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print("Oshibka")
```

Сам неопытный, но по гайдам что-то не могу решение найти.

Comment: Какие заголовки отправляете?

Answer (score 1):

```
items = soup.find('table', class_='sortable').find_all('tr')[1:]
```